# jQuery .width(val) error in IE - invalid argument

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

After loading an internal div (#book_table) via ajax, I want to resize the width of the body to accommodate the larger content.

```
var new_width = parseInt($('#book_table').css('width'))+407;
$('body').width(new_width);
```

Works in FF and Safari, but fails in IE with "Invalid argument". In the unpacked jQuery 1.3.1, it's line 1049:

```
elem[ name ] = value;
```

Passing a literal value, however, works in IE:

```
$('body').width(1200);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try:

```
var new_width = $('#book_table').width() + 407;
$('body').width(new_width);
```

Using `css('width')` is returning a string with the 'px' extension rather than simply a number.  Firefox can properly parse `"100px"` to be `100` with `parseInt`, but it looks like IE does not.

Using `width()` will just return an integer, which also removes the need to call `parseInt`.