# JQuery dynamic img load and set width not working in IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer

I am writing a function based on a dynamic image that is pulled in based on the clients logo.  This logo auto fills inside the logoContainer div.  I am setting the width dynamically so I can have the logo centered properly with margin: 0 auto no matter what logo gets pulled in since specifying for every logo as we get new clients takes too long.

This function specifically works in chrome and firefox, but does not work in any version of IE.  The function stops loading on the .load, but is not providing any errors.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logoIMG").load(function() {
        $("#logoContainer").css("width",$(this).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: have a look at this...http://stackoverflow.com/a/933575/235710

Comment: This fixes IE and still works in firefox, but for some reason the code in that link breaks it in chrome causing it to pass a value of 0 for the width.  I have it enclosed in a $(document).ready() function like my above code, but still does not work.  I ican always do a browser check, though I was trying to avoid using browser version checks.